# issue when deploy basic auth in kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, basic-authentication, dashboard

I try to add a basic authentication to my kubernetes cluster by changing the file. 
/etc/kubernetes/manifest/kubernetes-apiserver.yaml
There i add 3 flags

- -- basic-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/basic-auth.csv
- -- authorization-mode=ABAC
- -- authentication-mode=basic

But when i add those lines and i restart my system. My kubernetes freezes and won't start. Is this the right way to add flags to an already running kubernetes cluster ? Is this the right way to add basic authentication to kubernetes dashboard ?

I used this tutorial for the basic authentication: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control#basic

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually you doing everything right, but the problem is that for Modern Kubernetes version, at least for 1.9, `authentication-mode` is not a valid CLI flag for API server. All available flags you can check in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-apiserver/).
It is a bit outdated documentation in the repo. Actually, basic authentification [will be enabled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#static-password-file) when you provided `basic-auth-file` option.

So, just remove `authentication-mode` flag and use only `basic-auth-file` and `authorization-mode`.  If should help.

For enable a user/password authorization, based on [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Dashboard-arguments) of dashboard, you need to add `authentication-mode` CLI arg to a Dashboard.

Comment: I tried it without the authentication mode , just the other 2 but it didn't work. The staps are 
1. Change the file
2. Reboot system / restart kubelet service
Too apply the changes.

Comment: Where can i find the logs for the api server , there isn't a file /var/log/kube-apiserver.log ?

Comment: Depends of your installation, but that is a valid path too. And can you clarify a bit what exactly not working, all cluster or just a dashboard?

Comment: My cluster is working and i can access my kubernetes dashboard with the default login. With the token i can get access to my dashboard. But i want to add some kind of a login screen with a username and password. The dashboard will be exposed through NodePort so that the entire network will can get access to it. It get's interesting when i can create a login page so that i can create login credentials for my network.

Comment: Hm. It is bit not clear for me which Login screen you need. Do you have something like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2285385/30416718-8ee657d8-992d-11e7-84c8-9ba5f4c78bb2.png)? Can you show me which options available?

Comment: Indeed I have exactly that screen. 
But i want to know if it's possible to create a login screen with basic credentials . 

USER : 
PASSWD:

Comment: What do you mean add cli arg to a Dash board ?

Comment: Command line argument. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/41a1861c39b727278b7a1166b8ee9fccabd108d9/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml#L122) is example of that argument for dashboard. Add new one like that.